# DumpCount, DumpFolder for WER on Windows 2012 R2 server not working

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-error-reporting

I have an application which crashes every time on win 2012 server and generates a huge amount of dumps in the app folder. To restrict this to a minimum, I have been trying to set `DumpCount` and `LocalDumps` settings as per article here but doesn't help, dumps are generated too many and causing disk problems.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/wer-settings

Notice that I have set registry as

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\MyApp.exe
```

and within this *MyApp.exe* with parameters below

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\CrashMe.exe]
"DumpFolder"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,54,00,65,00,6d,00,70,00,5c,00,64,00,75,\
  00,6d,00,70,00,73,00,00,00
"DumpType"=dword:00000002
"DumpCount"=dword:00000003
```

Even I did try settings in `HKCU` and `WOW6432Node` note, restart but doesn't help.

Also, notice that I did testing on Win10 client, it works there!

Comment: Note that I have full read/write access on local app folder and c:\temp where I am trying to generate dumps

Comment: Improved formatting and updated tags

Comment: Did you ever solve this?